# Why is DPO necessary when the exact solution for RLHF/PPO is already available?

Tags: rlhf

I came across an interesting paper on improving RLHF (essentially getting rid of the RL part), highly recommended by Andrew Ng, and receiving already 140 citations in 1 month (though the preprint probably came out much earlier): https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.18290

The main idea is that the RL objective in RLHF can be solved exactly if we know the short term reward function $r(x, y)$.
[image]

Here $\pi_{\rm{ref}}$ is some starting policy, such as that given by pretrained language model, whereas $\pi_r$ is the optimal policy we want to learn (e.g., chatgpt).

The paper then derives some loss function that is differentiable with respect to the model parameter, which makes it amenable to traditional supervised pairwise fine-tuning, without resorting to RL.
[image]

Of course, their approach does not require learning the short term reward function $r(x,y)$ first (which is done in the 2nd stage of RLHF, i.e., pairwise Fine-Tuning Phase).

But my question is, why not do the fine-tuning and simply plug in the learned $r(x, y)$ into the optimal policy formula (4)? This way, all the clever math deriving $L_{\rm{DPO}}$ seems unnecessary. I understand the normalization constant $Z(x)$ makes $\pi_r(y |x)$ difficult to compute exact, but do we really need to compute it exactly? We just need to know the relative preference between two actions given the current state, so $\pi_r(y_a |x) / \pi_l(y_b | x)$ should be sufficient, isn't it?